Specify code as optimised in debug configuration
Generally, I always develop in the debug configuration, as I find it very useful and the fact that its a little slower doesn't hamper productivity.
However, I have some code that runs particularly slowly in debug, around 10x slower, which for what I am doing does slow down development.
In this specific case, its a static method with many iterations of a loop.
I was wondering if there was a way to mark a file or class or similar such that its optimised as though it was release, even though the project configuration is set to debug?
I appreciate I could probably achieve this by moving all the code to another project, reference that project, and have that project to always compile as release, but was wondering if it could be done inside the project instead?
